# Python: os.getcwd() unchanged after refactor file location

Tags: python, operating-system, pycharm

Saying I create `a.py` under `path/to/somewhere/`. And later in the IDE(pycharm), I refactor it to `path/to/another_place/`.

But when I run `a.py` later, `os.getcwd()` show its working directory is still in `path/to/somewhere`. ( `os.listdir('.')` also show it is in original place.)

The following picture is what I meet [image: picture], `makeimg.py` is originally in `learn_function`

I am new to python and I don't understand how a file/modoule locate itself.

Am I do something wrong? or it is a bug?

Comment: where a file is has nothing to do with your cwd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.getcwd()` returns the **c**urrent **w**orking **d**irectory, it may/may not be the directory in which the your script exists, its the directory from which the script was run. Most probably in your PyCharm `Run/Debug` configuration you have set the Working directory to `path/to/somewhere` .

From [`run/debug configuration` doc page](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/run-debug-configuration-python.html) for pycharm -

> Working directory -   Specify a directory to be used by the running task.
>
> When a default run/debug configuration is created by the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F10</kbd> , or by choosing Run on the context menu of a script, the working directory is the one that contains the executable script. This directory may differ from the project directory.

Ideally your code should not depend on the current working directory , since you can run a python file from anywhere using absolute path to the python file.

Instead if you want the path in which the script resides, use `__file__` to get that path in the script.

Example -

```
print(__file__)
```

This should print the script's path (as given in `sys.argv[0]`).

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.

Comment: the working directory is the one that contains the executable script -> this is what I need, thanks